# How is "money loaned to friend" classified on FAFSA?

Tags: fafsa

I'm filling out FAFSA for graduate school and wonder how I should classify the money I loan to a friend.

It's a big amount (~ $10,000) and was transferred informally, i.e. I just cut him a check with a written document between us.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it's an asset - a note you hold and your friend promised to repay you.

Comment: Yep. Note that if it was large enough to be running into Gift Taxes you'd want to be a lot more formal about this.

Comment: If I need to provide supporting document to show this, what kind of document can I use?

Comment: That written document. And repayment statements, probably.